# Is there support for Certificate Authentication in Swagger UI?

Tags: authentication, certificate, swagger-ui, authorize

Is there support for Client Certificate Authentication in Swagger UI? If yes, could someone provide an example of enabling it in a solution using asp.net core 5 and Swashbuckle, or point me to a url which has a good example of the same.

Comment: Swaggerui does not support certificate authentication because you don't need to do anything special to do certificate authentication. when you call an API which needs a certificate for authentication, the browser will ask for certificate to be used for authentication. only drawaback is that you can only choose certificate which is installed in windows certificate store.